# A book about a boy raised by dragons

Tags: story-identification, dragons

Due to the passage of time, I have forgotten the title of the book. It may be something along the lines of 'The Dragons of-' There are dragons, living in secret. Humans have some knowledge that they're still around. Anyway, this one dragon brings a human baby back, and after some years, returns him to the human world.

There's also something about the moon not being too fond of dragons, white dragons that live on the moon, and some rather nasty ones that live on the dark side.

Cover was of night sky, with a green dragon fighting a white one.

Comment: When did you read this book? And was it new(ish) then? Do you remember the names of any characters or places?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [The Dragons Of North Chittendon](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/951518.The_Dragons_Of_North_Chittendon) by Susan Fromberg Schaeffer.

From [this review](http://www.goodreads.com/review/show/362355075?book_show_action=true) on Goodreads

> Arthur is the son of a dragon killed rescuing humans. Patrick is the
>   human he one day rescues as a baby, and shares milk with. A human who
>   shares dragon's milk becomes bound to that dragon in dreams. Patrick
>   becomes a witness to Arthur's life, and the war of the dragons versus
>   the moon.
>
> Yeah, that's right, the moon. The moon at the beginning of creation
>   once loved the white dragons that lived there on its light side. But
>   then it grew jealous over their beauty, and the beauty of the sun
>   itself. It tried to make war against them both, but was defeated, and
>   forced back into space to orbit us, isolated. Its air was taken away
>   to prevent any more dragons from visiting it, and soon it grew angry
>   at them, and used its power of the tides to hurt dragons whenever it
>   could.

[image]

Comment: Yep, that's it. Thanks!